# MSVC compiled program is 3x slower than program, compiled with MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

I need to write some addon for NodeJS. Since addon should work on Windows, I need to compile it with MSVC. But after compilation I discovered that addon was slower than original program. So, after check, I made a conclusion that problem is MSVC. See results below. So, I don't understand, why MSVC produce so slow program. Can I optimize compilation with MSVC in some way, to reach speed of MinGW compiled program? Or simply MSVC produce less optimized code and maximum optimization for MSVC is already reached?

---

- Compiler: g++ (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
  12.1.0
- Compilation: g++ -O3 main.cpp
- Execution time: 18517 ms

---

- Compiler: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31629 for x64 (Toolset v143, SDK 10.0.20348.0)
- Compilation: cl /O2 main.cpp
- Execution time: 58144 ms

---

Notes:

1. I added `swap(word1, word2)` only to prevent MinGW optimization, that results in 0s execution time.
2. If I switch from `string` to `char[]` the execution time in MinGW almost not change (1-2s faster), but it reduces significantly in MSVC - 36 s after switch. If I replace with vector of int it reduces again to 25 s.

---

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int cached[6];
int SIZE;

void setSize(int size) {
    SIZE = size;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        cached[i] = pow(3, i);
}

int getMask(const string& guess, const string& answer) {
    int results[6];
    bool visited[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (guess[i] == answer[i]) {
            results[i] = 2;
            visited[i] = true;
        }
        else {
            results[i] = 0;
            visited[i] = false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (results[i] != 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                if (answer[j] == guess[i] && !visited[j]) {
                    results[i] = 1;
                    visited[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int result = results[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        result += results[i] * cached[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    setSize(6);

    int sum = 0;
    auto t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    string word1 = "abcdef";
    string word2 = "fedcba";

    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30000; j++) {
            sum += getMask(word1, word2);
            swap(word1, word2);
        }
    }

    auto t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << "[ms]" << endl;

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the generated assembly?

Comment: Which optimization settings were used with both toolchains?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I leave all as default.

Comment: Well, how can we compare them then? They're not necessarily the same for different build systems. `RELEASE` mode is almost meaningless to specify that.

Comment: Maybe the MSVC build depends on runtime libraries that need some time to load. MinGW-w64 us truly native and has no dependencies on large runtime libraries. You could test this by verifying if the delay is on load or after load during actual execution.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added all options that put Visual Studio when build solution

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i just downloaded MinGW from official site and compiled with -O3 flag. Execution time is same 18 seconds.

Comment: @BrechtSanders and? this libraries is loading meanwhile mainthread is running? But for small iterations count programs finishes fast.

Comment: Does MSVC still use checked iterators by default? You may want to check all the settings and disable a few things that are still enabled in release mode.

Comment: It isn't that uncommon for msvc to produce code slower than other compilers. You could also try -O2 with gcc, and also try clang for another datapoint.